# Sending multiple attachments using BULK API

Tags: bulk-api

I want to send multiple attachments to SalesForce using Bulk API.

please tell me what should be the endpoint in this case,what should be my CSV format ,what all headers I'll be including and other stuff if you know which could help me

Comment: If you want to achieve it using Curl then this is the link. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/binary_intro.htm I'm also struggling to see how it can be achieved using Java or any other language.

Comment: Please see the related question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34779/unable-to-upload-an-attachment-bulk-api

Comment: I have achieved the task without using CURL

Comment: Using Apex Dataloader tool? or programming?

Comment: Programming...using Salesforce Bulk API calls

Comment: I would appreciate if you could please share some code snippets.. :)

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/

Read the section "Loading binary Attachments'.