# Unable to upload an Attachment - Bulk API

Tags: attachment, java, error, bulk-api

I'm using Bulk API to upload attachments and getting an error:

```
InvalidBatch : Failed to parse CSV header.
      Number of Records Processed: 0
```

While I'm getting following error at the Salesforce side:

```
<error xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <exceptionCode>InvalidBatch</exceptionCode>
    <exceptionMessage>Records not processed</exceptionMessage>
</error>
```

I'm using Java, and it seems it errors while creating the batches like:

```
private static void createBatch(FileOutputStream tmpOut, File tmpFile,
        List<BatchInfo> batchInfos, BulkConnection connection, JobInfo jobInfo)
throws IOException, AsyncApiException {
    tmpOut.flush();
    tmpOut.close();
    FileInputStream tmpInputStream = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
    try {
        Map<String, InputStream> attachments = new HashMap<String, InputStream>();
        attachments.put("MyFile1.txt", new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\upload\\2014-04-18_231314.png"));

        BatchInfo batchInfo = connection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(jobInfo, tmpInputStream, attachments);

        System.out.println(batchInfo!=null ? "BatchInfo is not null " : " BatchInfo is Null "); // I'm getting "BatchInfo is not null"
        batchInfos.add(batchInfo);
    } finally {
        tmpInputStream.close();
    }
} // END private void createBatch()
```

While for creating the job, I'm making sure the following parameters are set:

```
operation : OperationEnum.insert
object : Attachment
contentType : ContentType.ZIP_CSV
```

The CSV file as an input is:

```
Name,ParentId,Body
2014-04-18_231314.png,0019000000tZhfe,C:\Users\user\Desktop\upload\2014-04-18_231314.png
```

The above input is working fine using Apex Dataloader.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or is there anything I'm missing. I'm calling the method named: `uploadBinaryAttachmentUsingBulkAPI()` from this code: [PasteBin Code](http://pastebin.com/US53nJXQ).

**EDIT:**
I'm using Bulk API version 27.0.

Comment: How many attachments are you trying to upload? What size are they?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to upload only one attachment. But I would like to attach multiple attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Bulk API version 30 documentation gives the curl implementation by wrapping up all the contents in `Zip` containing a manifest file named `request.txt`. I got the solution using version 27.

I tried using multiple inputs in which 3rd one worked as desired. Now, I'm able to upload multiple attachments.

1. I provided the `Zip file path` as `tmpInpuStream` and got the same error by calling:

   connection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(jobInfo, tmpInputStream, attachments);

   (Same Error)
2. Provided the path of menifest file as `request.txt` by calling:

   connection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(jobInfo, tmpInputStream, attachments);

   (Same Error)
3. After analyzing the Apex Data Loader functionality, I provided the path of menifest file as request.csv and calling: `(It worked)`

   connection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(jobInfo, tmpInputStream, attachments);

   bypassing createCSVFromBatches() method and the `Name` in `Menifest` file matching the `Key` of `attachments` Map.

   Also, the `value` of `attachments` `Map` containing the `absolute` path of File and `Body` of `menifest` file containing the `relative` path using `#`.
   Please find the code snippet attached here [Binary File Attachments using Bulk API.](http://pastebin.com/w2rYBFAF)